# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT when connecting to port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, aws-devops

I tried to connect my AWS EC2 instance with Jenkins. After security configuration I open the IP address with port 8080 but it shows this timeout error:

```
This site can’t be reached my_ip_address took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Comment: Are _you_ able to connect to port 8080 on that EC2 instance from your own computer? What is the configuration of the Security Group attached to that instance?

Comment: i used port as 8080 ip as my ipv4